# SSRS grouping giving blank rows

Tags: reporting-services, grouping

Apologies for the simple question but it's driving me crazy.

I am trying to show how many items a surveyor has seen in a year.  I am counting the unique identifier as the expression for the number of items seen.

I have added grouping and included my sum within the groups as per the report link here:- (I'm new so can't post pics yet)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZNUM.png

But when I preview it, it shows a blank row next to the sum.
[Report in preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9UaL.png)

So the first row shows 19 and there are 19 blank rows in the column next to it.  I try to delete that column but then I get the message table must include one column.

What am I doing wrong and wht is the right way to do this?

Many thanks for any help

Natalie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bit that's left over on the right is the "Details" region - essentially where you want the detail of your report to live.

Try putting your `sum()` in there, deleting the "Details" group, and deleting the column where your `sum()` is now.